# C++ interview question involving class pointers

Tags: c++

Lets say there is a base class pointer which is pointing to a base class object:

```
baseclass *bptr;
bptr= new baseclass;
```

now if i do

```
bptr= new derived;
```

what is the problem  here?

Comment: Did you have just this or the declaration of the classes?

Comment: I'm going to go with an inconsistent naming scheme.  If you have `baseclass` logically you would also have `derivedclass`.  Also, the spacing is all sorts of wrong.  *Everybody* knows the asterisk belongs with the type, not the variable.

Comment: @Dennis Logically the asterisk belongs to the type but syntactically it belongs to the variable. Try this and tell me if ptr2 is a pointer or not: `MyClass* ptr1, ptr2;`.

Comment: @Vite Falcon: That's why nobody uses multiple declarations on one line.

Comment: @DeadMG that's not WHY nobody uses multiple declarations on one line. That's not even a reason why no one should use multiple declarations. It's just because people are not fully aware of the syntax. When I said logically, I meant that's how we (humans) relate things, but does that mean that's how it's supposed to be?
I was pointing out Dennis the statement he made `Everybody knows the asterisk belongs with the type, not the variable.` was wrong because   in a declaration it DOES belong to a type.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The obvious answer is that you're leaking the original base class object.

Comment: this was my answer ...actually ..but he hinted me of any other problem that i could figure out.

Comment: One thing could be that the derived must actually be derived from base.

Comment: @benjamin button: If the base class destructor is not virtual then when you `delete bptr;` the derived class destructor is not called. But I don't know whether it is relevant here.

Comment: @Naveen: that is true, but if that's the answer the interviewer was looking for, then I'd say it was rather a trick question... it seems reasonable to me to assume that if a class is designed to be inherited from then it would have a virtual destructor.

Comment: @codeka: I agree..but the virtual destructor is a rather common interview question, so just a guess.

Comment: @Naveen: That's plain wrong. If the base class doesn't have a virtual destructor that's undefined behavior, not some destructor not being called.

Comment: We could add that, if either `baseclass` or `derived` have no parameterless constructor, the code will not compile. Silly, indeed, but no sillier than having you guess whether the classes are correctly written or not when you cannot see them. Besides, if the answer is related to the lack of a virtual destructor, the second line is unnecessary.

Answer (score 7):

Other than the obvious memory leak it depends on the definition of `baseclass` and `derived` some of the problems could be:

1. `derived` is not publicly derived from `baseclass` (if so it's a horrible question to ask in an interview)
2. `baseclass` does not have a virtual destructor (in which case it's unsafe to `delete bptr;`)

Answer (score 5):

If I were you I would turn back and ask your interviewer couple of questions:

1. Are you sure this is the only code snippet available and in that case my answer's an educated guess, nothing more.
2. Is there some sort of a memory mgmt scheme for baseclass and derived? In that case we need to look into the operator new definitions which ain't provided.
3. If no memory mgmt, then are baseclass or derived smart pointer types that do reference counting? No leaks in those cases either.
4. If no smart types, then of course this looks like a memory leak.

And please, having virtual destructors etc come into place only if you have the class definitions. Perhaps the interviewer is secretly looking for clairvoyant types.

Arpan

Answer (score 2):

> what is the problem here?

If the answer of ("a memory leak") is not accepted, the problem is either the question or the interviewer ;)

Answer (score 1):

In first line, you declared a pointer.
In second line, you give it a reference in memory.
in line 3, you give IT another reference in memory.

the first reference you gave to the pointer is leaked...you can never get it back.

Answer (score 1):

Was he trying to get to the [Circle Ellipse problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem)?  If derived is a specialisation of baseclass some public methods on baseclass may no longer have a meaning e.g. if Circle is derived from Ellipse and Ellipse has a method called stretch() which stretches the ellipse in one axis, what do you do when the method is called on an instance of Circle?

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning the pointer without releasing the memory allocated for the previous object. This can result in memory leak, in case no body else has stored the value of `bptr` before reassigning it.

Answer (score 0):

Does `baseclass` have a virtual destructor?  If not, that could be bad too (in addition to obvious leak).

Answer (score 0):

The only problem occurs if the class destructor is not defined as virtual. In this scenario, it will cause memory leak

Answer (score 0):

There is **no syntax problem** but you are loosing the address of the "baseclass" instance by assigning a new value to "bptr" variable. This results in a memory leak, as the address of the first instanciated class is lost.

Answer (score 0):

I'd answer this interview question like so:

From the limited code snippet provided it's clear that a memory leak will ensue when we assign the pointer to an instance of this derived class, as we have no other pointers accessing the base object.   However it's impossible to say anymore about the code snippet without seeing the definitions of both classes, and seeing the relationship between the two classes.